# How can I read from a website?

Tags: vb.net, automation, bots

I'm trying to make a bot, how can I read the value like the 1800 / 1800 from a website?

[image]

```
            Console.WriteLine("Health: ")
            Console.WriteLine("Energy: ")
            Console.WriteLine("Cash: ")
            Console.WriteLine("Level: ")
```

I'm making a console application, trying to get the value. Like if the health is lower then 1000/1800 then it's going to execute a send key. Like send the key "0" to the website.

Thanks,
Prince

Comment: Please do not post [duplicate questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766408/how-can-i-read-from-a-website-c-sharp)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is a good and popular toolkit to scrape information from web pages.

> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).

For an introduction to using it have a look at:

http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/09/htmlagilitypack-article-series.html

If you get stuck at a particular step using it, by all means ask a new, detailed question on Stack Overflow.