# How can I read from a website? C#

Tags: c#, automation, bots

I'm trying to make a bot, how can I read the value like the 1800 / 1800 from a website?

[image]

```
        Console.WriteLine("Health: ")
        Console.WriteLine("Energy: ")
        Console.WriteLine("Cash: ")
        Console.WriteLine("Level: ")
```

I'm making a console application, trying to get the value. Like if the health is lower then 1000/1800 then it's going to execute a send key. Like send the key "0" to the website.

Thanks, Prince

Comment: What's going on here? 8 down-votes and no one backing with arguments? Might as well let him know what's wrong.

Comment: `Uri.ReadThePartIamInterestedIn(bool guess=true)`

Comment: @Measuring Screenscraping is generally frowned upon, so is making bots, combine the two and you have a recipe for downvotes. Sans an explanation one has to conclude you're making a bot to game the game.

Comment: @Measuring Then too, he's basically asking for someone else to write code for him.

Comment: @Measuring Make that 19 downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

trying using `WebClient.DownloadString`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring(v=vs.110).aspx

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
string reply = client.DownloadString ("http://google.com");
```

you then parse the document for the things you want. you can use the HTML Agility pack for that

http://html-agility-pack.net

Comment: Can you write an example?

Comment: note, that people don't often do this with things like C#, they will use javascript and inject directly into the webpage itself

Comment: @Keith Nicholas I'll have to assume he wants to make it an Windows executable for .. whatever purpose.

Comment: @SamuelMasih: If you have not *tried* to solve the problem, SO won't either. We aren't a living, breathing encyclopedia. If you need research, use Google.